# A tiny recursive crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script to crawl a website recursively until all the links connected to some tutorials are exhausted. It is working smoothly now. There is always room for improvement, though!

```
import requests
from lxml import html

Page_link="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
visited_links = []

def GrabbingData(url):
    base="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk"
    visited_links.append(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    title = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]//a/text()')
    link = tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]//a/@href')
    for i,j in zip(title,link):
        print(i,j)

    pagination=tree.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' woPaging ')]//a[@class='woPagingItem' or @class='woPagingNext']/@href")
    for nextp in pagination:
        url1 = str(base + nextp)
        if url1 not in visited_links:
            GrabbingData(url1)

GrabbingData(Page_link)
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain your reason for choosing recursion over iteration for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to make your solution recursive. Iterative approach in your case would be more intuitive and simple.

Moreover, there is a *better way to handle pagination* for this particular website - the paginated parts of the video catalog are following `http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/default-<number>.htm` pattern, which means that you can start with `number=1` up until you get `404` which would conclude the catalog:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


URL_PATTERN = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/default-{}.htm"

with requests.Session() as session:
    page_number = 1
    while True:
        response = session.get(URL_PATTERN.format(page_number))
        if response.status_code == 404:  # break once the page is not found
            break

        print("Processing page number {}..".format(page_number))

        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        for video_link in tree.xpath('//p[@class="woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle"]//a'):
            title = video_link.text
            link = video_link.attrib['href']

            print(title, link)

        page_number += 1
```

Notes about some of the improvements I've made:

- [re-using the same `Session` instance](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) - it results into a memory usage and performance improvement because it re-uses the same TCP connection:

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).
- instead of searching the entire tree for the "video" elements 2 times, looping over video link elements directly once
- *naming*: first of all, make sure to follow the [`lower_case_with_underscores` Python naming recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). And, try to avoid meaningless variables like `i` and `j` if not used as throwaway loop variables; `url1` was not a good variable choice as well
- follow other [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide recommendations - in particular, watch for the spaces around operators and newlines

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for such invaluable suggestions. I'll try to comply with from now on. You are really the legend.